# WCF webservice creation and displaying in winform application

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, wcf, web-services

I need a advice and help from wcf experienced professional.
is it possible to access mySql database of a php website from wcf web service. if yes , can u please show me the way how to create webservice which will have connection string to access database and in response will give data in xml format to my winform application. And my winform application will consume this data ! I know basic of web services like adding reference and consuming data from web hosting but never access database from webservice !

I tested it for Sql database with following code

```
[WebMethod]
        public string ReturnData()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            try
            {
                con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cn"].ConnectionString;
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM dataBaseName";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                if (cmd.ExecuteScalar() == null)
                {
                    return "Database Error !";
                }
                else
                {
                    return cmd.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return ex.ToString();
            }
            finally
            {
                if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                {
                    con.Open();
                }
            }

        }
```

but when  i consume it is showing error .. Please Guide !

Comment: Are you sure your query works? have you pasted it as is into a query tool and run it? You probably should not be using ExecuteScalar unless you are just expecting one value back.

Comment: Query is working fine in my local host , i just changed the connection string and uploaded to the hosting company website..i know connection string has right credentials ,and i am using executeScalar just for testing , but even it is not returning the first value .. any solution ?

Comment: Output the actual value of your connection string and post it, It sounds like it is an empty string

Answer (score 0):

> never access database from webservice

If you know rest of the things then this is not a difficult one at all. just change the connection provider i.e. [OledbConnectionProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.aspx).

Comment: Error is - Server was unable to process request. ---> The ConnectionString property has not been initialized.        And one more thing , when i upload my webservice in root folder and its dll in root bin folder it is working fine for "hello" function but when i upload it into a folder and then access it like www.myWebsite/webS/Service1.asmx  , it is showing 500 internal server error .. do you know the solution ?